# ASP.NET Core MVC - Complex Objects specific to a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm sort of learning on the fly (coming from a desktop perspective), so forgive me if this seems dumb.

This would be a CRUD type of application, so imagine if you have two controllers for data entry:

```
SupervisorController
EmployeeController
```

Now, let's say the User goes to https://whatever/SupervisorController and before I do anything, I need to create some objects specific to the Supervisor screen (e.g. I create an Access object, which reads some data from a source, which tells me what they have access to on that specific Supervisor screen).

OK, in my Index method I construct that object and pass it to my view. But, that object won't persist when say, another method for that controller is called, or say Refresh on the browser is clicked (the constructor for the controller is called each time).

And let's say that the user goes to the browser and types https://whatever/SupervisorController/AnotherMethod themselves. Well, I only constructed that object in my Index Method. So now I have to construct that same object, again, there? And pass it to this view?

Where I'm getting at is that if someone goes to any method of the SupervisorController, if the object isn't there, I want to construct some "supervisor" specific objects, keep them available in my "private member variables", until I'm done with SupervisorController. Meaning, if they move on to say EmployeeController, those objects can now go away.

At EmployeeController, I'll want something similar. Complex objects created specifically for Employee CRUD, that I won't need once I'm done with Employees.

I mean, I really don't want to create these objects and store them in the Session for the lifetime of the session, as they are really only needed for their specific controllers. On top of that, how much data do I really want to be storing in session memory before it gets to be too much!

But if I don't store them somewhere, I would have to re-create these objects for every action/method. I don't want to create them in every method of a specific controller (I could be going to a database to get some specific information). For example, I'm playing around with a Grid Control on my Index page, and when you reach that page, there's the initial call to the Index method, and then the grid itself makes a call to this Read method I have. So I would be creating that object twice!? On one call to https://whatever/SupervisorController?

How do people handle what I'm trying to achieve? Or is there some way I need to look at it now, and implement it to those guidelines?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing some fundamentals to MVC, way too broad a question. There is a free Pluralsight MVC5 course which should give you some basics to start with. Scott Allen explains it quite well.
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

Comment: Coming from desktop, **web** `HTTP` fundamentals matter:  `GET`, `POST` etc. A controller's methods respond based on the _http request_. So your "index" _typically_ will handle `GET`, while `form` submission _typically_ will be handled by a method that handles `POST`. Unlike desktop web/http is _stateless_ - relying on things like Session to "create" a sense of persistence/state.

Comment: Yes, coming from the "client" architecture you'd need to adjust to the most common web server architecture of doing things in a stateless way. If you need to take multiple steps to create some object you'd better use the database for it.